# Product list export without admin access

Tags: product-listing, database-connection

The title probably seems suspicious but this is an above-board question:

I routinely visit a company's Magento auction storefront and it's pretty time consuming to get through all of their categories and items when limited to just 36 results per page so I'm wondering if it's possible to connect to the store via whatever tool may exist to simple fetch a list of all currently available items (.csv, etc.) including SKU/item #, Qty, and Description, nothing more.

Thanks.

Comment: use eScraper tool or service to scrape the listings without access

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this via a custom module.
Inside the module directory, create a controller file
**app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Export.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;


use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;


class Export extends Action
{
    protected $password = 'Admin@123'; // Change this to your desired password
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $fileFactory;
    protected $productCollectionFactory;
    protected $registry;


    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        FileFactory $fileFactory,
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        Registry $registry
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $password = $this->getRequest()->getParam('password');


        if ($this->isPasswordValid($password)) {
            // Password is valid, execute your controller logic here
            $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_RAW);
            $result->setContents('Controller Action Executed Successfully!');
            $products = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
        $products->addAttributeToSelect('*'); // Add attributes you want to export


        // Set headers
        $fileName = 'product_list.csv';
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' . $fileName);


        // Create CSV
        $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        fputcsv($output, $this->getHeader());


        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $data = $this->getProductData($product);
            fputcsv($output, $data);
        }


        fclose($output);
            return $result;
        } else {
            // Password is invalid, return an error
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Invalid Password.'));
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setPath('/');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
    }
    private function isPasswordValid($enteredPassword)
    {
        return $enteredPassword === $this->password;
    }
    protected function getHeader()
    {
        // Modify this array to include the attributes you want to export
        return ['sku', 'name', 'qty', 'price', 'description'];
    }


    protected function getProductData($product)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
        // Modify this array to include the attributes you want to export
        return [
            $product->getSku(),
            $product->getName(),
            $StockState->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId()),
            $product->getPrice(),
            $product->getDescription(),
        ];
    }
}
```

Create **routes.xml** file in **Vendor/Module/etc/frontend**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
   <!--define id for frontend route is “standard”-->
   <router id="standard">
       <!--Route name-->
       <route id="post" frontName="post">
           <!--Module name-->
           <module name="Vendor_Module" />
       </route>
   </router>
</config>
```

Please hit the below Url to export the CSV file:

**http://{{hostname}}/magentocom/post/index/export/password/Admin@123**

**Admin@123** is your password you can set in **export.php** file from line number 14

**Output Look Like :** https://prnt.sc/Dv63PJUN6lxP